# Object to decimal casting can't be implemented

Tags: c#, .net

I try to cast from Object type to decimal:

```
 Object obj = new Object();
 obj = 10;
 decimal dec = (decimal)obj;
```

but in this row  **decimal dec = (decimal)obj** , I get this Exception:

**Specified cast is not valid.**

Any idea why this unboxing can't be implemented?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

which is why you have `Convert.ToDecimal()` boxing and unboxing can only happen between same types.

`10` literal is represented in C# compiler as an System.Int32(correct me if I am wrong people) and hence unboxing of this to a decimal will result in error

Answer (score 2):

You can only unbox a value type to its original type or the nullable equivalent version of that type.

For the reason behind this read this [Eric Lippert's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

When you write `obj = 10;`, object has value of type int.

Try this:

```
Object obj = new Object();
obj = 10M;
decimal dec = (decimal)obj;
```

or this:

```
Object obj = new Object();
obj = 10;
decimal dec = (decimal)(int)obj;
```

You should read [Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) article on msdn.

> For the unboxing of value types to succeed at run time, the item being
>   unboxed must be a reference to an object that was previously created
>   by boxing an instance of that value type. Attempting to unbox null
>   causes a NullReferenceException. Attempting to unbox a reference to an
>   incompatible value type causes an InvalidCastException.

Comment: how about `Convert.ToDecimal()`?

Comment: @Aniket `Convert.ToDecimal()` is a good solution :)